# If statement in excel don't return false value

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, find

I'm trying to understand why false statement is not working in this formula below.

```
=IF(FIND("(Pic";A1);LEFT(A1; FIND("(Pic";A1)-1);A1)
```

If in cell A1 find the string **(Pic** I just want to execute this part of code above:

```
LEFT(A1; FIND("(Pic";A1)-1)
```

and it's working. When the formula find **(Pic** it's executing properly.
But when the formula don't find **(Pic** I want to just take the whole string and that's why after the true statement, I just put
 `;A1)` 
But instead of return the value inside of A1, it's returning **#VALUE!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND("(Pic";A2);LEFT(A2;FIND("(Pic";A2)-1);A2);A2)
```

Comment: The `IF` is redundant. Try: `=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("(Pic",A2)-1),A2)`, obviously swap the comma for a semi-colon.